# Which element can I use instead of table that have the same properties?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have many pictures with the same size and I want to use them for a slideshow,
so they have to be in one row and maybe the width of this row be larger than width of the window and I want to some pictures go out of screen instead of they go in next line.
Before now I used table to make them in one row and I just moved the table to make this slideshow. [like this:]

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   ...
</table>
```

but I want to use another element [ for example a div with some CSS rules that have a property like that table ] because table make some problems in my page.

Comment: Is your table causing problems because you are not using `<tr>` and `<td>` tags?  Or did you miss this out when pasting example code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with minimal code and no "hacks".

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;">
       <img src="..." />
       <img src="..." />
       <img src="..." />
       <img src="..." />
       <img src="..." />
       <img src="..." />
       ...
    </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U757v/2/)**

Comment: thanks a lot.. and is there any way to remove the space between pictures after styling the div?

Comment: Set margin:0px; for the images.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your code?

Comment: i tried -4px for margin and it works;) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly, an unordered list ist used in such slider plugins.

```
<ul>
   <li><img .../></li>
   <li><img .../></li>
   <li><img .../></li>
</ul>
```

with

```
li{float:left;}
```

This has the advantage, that you can put more elements into the `<li>` elements (e.g. an image + description + short text).

but you could use a plain div as well

```
<div>
  <img />
  <img />
</div>
```

If you want more elements grouped together (e.g. an Explanation for the images) you have to wrap them with additional divs. (which effectively brings you back to the ul...)

```
<div>
  <div><img /> Text</div>
  <div><img /> more Text</div>
</div>
```

And just for you information, the correct way to use a table is:

```
<table>
   <tr>        <!-- the row -->
     <td></td> <!-- columns -->
     <td></td> <!-- columns -->
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey now used to this format

```
<div class="slideshow">
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   ...
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.slideshow{
white-space: nowrap;
}
.slideshow img{
vertical-align:top;
}
```